# Scala Spark - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to scala spark and its MLlib, and currently I'm struggling against an error that I don't know why it is happening.

I have an RDD with multiple partitions, containing data like this (output from take(#)):

```
Array[TermDoc] = Array(TermDoc(142389495503925248,Set(NEU),ArrayBuffer(salg, veotv, día, largooooo)), TermDoc(142389933619945473,Set(NEU),ArrayBuffer(librar, ayudar, bes, graci)), TermDoc(142391947707940864,Set(P),ArrayBuffer(graci, mar)), TermDoc(142416095012339712,Set(N+),ArrayBuffer(off, pensand, regalit, sind, va, sgae, van, corrupt, intent, sacar, conclusion, intent)), TermDoc(142422495721562112,Set(P+),ArrayBuffer(conozc, alguien, q, adict, dram, ja, ja, ja, suen, d)), TermDoc(142424715175280640,Set(NEU),ArrayBuffer(rt, si, amas, alguien, dejal, libr, si, grit, hombr, paurubi)), TermDoc(142483342040907776,Set(P+),ArrayBuffer(toca, grabacion, dl, especial, navideñ, mari, crism)), TermDoc(142493511634259968,Set(NEU))
```

Since there's an output, I assume that the RDD is not empty, but when I try to execute:

```
val count = rdd.count()

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.init(TraversableLike.scala:475)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.init(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:129)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$.buildDocument(<console>:58)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1598)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/03/13 10:15:11 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.init(TraversableLike.scala:475)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.init(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:129)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$.buildDocument(<console>:58)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at $line24.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1598)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/03/13 10:15:11 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/03/13 10:15:11 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
17/03/13 10:15:11 WARN spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
17/03/13 10:15:11 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener SQLListener threw an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLListener.onTaskEnd(SQLListener.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.init(TraversableLike.scala:475)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.init(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:129)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$.buildDocument(<console>:58)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1598)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1940)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:62)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:67)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:69)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:71)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:73)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:75)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:77)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:79)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:81)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:83)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:85)
        at <init>(<console>:87)
        at .<init>(<console>:91)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.init(TraversableLike.scala:475)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.init(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:129)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.init(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$.buildDocument(<console>:58)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$TweetParser$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1598)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Apparently, it is saying that I'm trying to call count on an empty RDD. What's happening? It also fails with this line:

```
val terms = termDocsRdd.flatMap(_.terms).distinct().sortBy(identity)
```

Same **empty.init** exception.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Adding required information

```
object TweetParser extends Serializable{

  val headerPart = "polarity"

  val mentionRegex = """@(.)+?\s""".r

  val fullRegex = """(\d+),(.+?),(N|P|NEU|NONE)(,\w+|;\w+)*""".r

  def parseAll(csvFiles: Iterable[String], sc: SparkContext): RDD[Document] = {
    val csv = sc.textFile(csvFiles mkString ",")
    //val docs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Document]

    val docs = csv.filter(!_.contains(headerPart)).map(buildDocument(_))
    docs
    //docs.filter(!_.docId.equals("INVALID"))
  }

  def buildDocument(line: String): Document = {

    val lineSplit = line.split(",")
    val id = lineSplit.head
    val txt = lineSplit.tail.init.init.mkString(",")
    val sent = lineSplit.init.last
    val opt = lineSplit.last

    if (id != null && txt != null && sent != null) {
      if (txt.equals("")) {
        //the line does not contain the option after sentiment
        new Document(id, mentionRegex.replaceAllIn(sent, ""), Set(opt))
      } else {
        new Document(id, mentionRegex.replaceAllIn(txt, ""), Set(sent))
      }
    } else {
      println("Invalid")
      new Document("INVALID")
    }
  }
}

case class Document(docId: String, body: String = "", labels: Set[String] = Set.empty)
```

Tokenizer object:

```
import java.io.StringReader

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.es.SpanishAnalyzer
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object Tokenizer extends Serializable {

  //val LuceneVersion = Version.LUCENE_5_1_0

  def tokenizeAll(docs: RDD[Document]) = docs.map(tokenize)

  def tokenize(doc: Document): TermDoc = TermDoc(doc.docId, doc.labels, tokenize(doc.body))

  def tokenize(content: String): Seq[String] = {
    val result = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    /*content.split("\n").foreach(line => line.split(" ").foreach(
      word => if (word.startsWith("#")) result += word.substring(1) else word
    ))*/
    val analyzer = new SpanishAnalyzer()
    analyzer.setVersion(Version.LUCENE_5_1_0)
    val tReader = new StringReader(content)
    val tStream = analyzer.tokenStream("", tReader)
    val term = tStream.addAttribute(classOf[CharTermAttribute])

    tStream.reset()
    while (tStream.incrementToken()) {
      val termValue = term.toString
      if (termValue.startsWith("#")) {
        result += termValue.substring(1)
      }
      else {
        result += termValue
      }
    }

    result
  }
}

case class TermDoc(doc: String, labels: Set[String], terms: Seq[String])
```

Driver:

```
val csvFiles = List("/path/to/file.csv", "/path/to/file2.csv", "/path/to/file3.csv")

val docs = TweetParser.parseAll(csvFiles, sc)

val termDocsRdd = Tokenizer.tokenizeAll(docs)

val numDocs = termDocsRdd.count()

val terms = termDocsRdd.flatMap(_.terms).distinct().sortBy(identity)
```

I'm testing this at spark-shell. That's why driver looks like this. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here would be very helpful

Comment: How are you creating those RDDs?

Comment: Could you show us the `buildDocument` method?

Comment: Just edited question adding required info! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently, it is saying that I'm trying to call count on an empty RDD

Actually - no, that's not what the error says. `count` triggers the computation of this RDD, and this exception is thrown while calculating one of the RDD's records.

Specifically, the error states:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.init

This is probably thrown from one of these expressions within `buildDocument`:

```
val txt = lineSplit.tail.init.init.mkString(",")
val sent = lineSplit.init.last
```

This code fragment assumes `lineSplit` is a collection with **at least 3 elements** - and the exception you see is the result of that assumption being incorrect for at least one record: for example, if `lineSplit` had just 2 elements, `lineSplit.tail.init` would be an empty collection, and therefore `lineSplit.tail.init.init` would throw the exception you see.

To overcome this - you can rewrite your "parsing" method to handle such irregularities in the data properly:

- Wrap it with a `Try(...)` and filter only the successful records, e.g.:

  ```
  import scala.util.{Try, Success}

  def parseAll(csvFiles: Iterable[String], sc: SparkContext): RDD[Document] = {
    val csv = sc.textFile(csvFiles mkString ",")

    val docs = csv.filter(!_.contains(headerPart))
      .map(s => Try(buildDocument(s)))
      .collect { case Success(v) => v }

    docs
  }
  ```
- Change the parsing so that "missing" parts of `lineSplit` will be set to `null` (as the following lines seem to expect), e.g.:

  ```
  def buildDocument(line: String): Document = {
    val (id, txt, sent, opt) = line.split(",").padTo(5, null) match {
      case Array(a,b,c,d,e,_*) => (a, s"$b,$c", d, e)
    }

    // continue as before....
  }
  ```